# Como realizar una Imagen Relativa con Ireport +java

Tags: java

Tengo mi Ireport de Empresas pero al momento que lo quiero importa(En un formato zip) al momento de que estoy en otra maquina y necesito abrir el reporte me aparece como si la imagen no existiera entonces me dijeron que buscara la manera de convertir la imagen en una relativa [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUnYQ.png)

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).